# DB design for video-annotations, where annotations have no unique id

Tags: database-design

Right now i have a program in java with 2 classes:

```
public class Video {                                                              
    private String id;                      
    private List<Annotation> annotations;   
    ...
}
```

and

```
public class Annotation{                                                              
    private String id;    
    ...                 
}
```

So each video can have lots of annotations and annotation can be displayed only in 1 video. It should be one(video)-to-many(annotation) relation, but the problem is: annotations don't have unique ids across all videos. Something like this:

```
Video id=1:
Annotation id=1; 
Annotation id=2; 

Video id=2:
Annotation id=1; 
Annotation id=2;
```

I can't change annotations id generation, because i get them in xml from different server and they should stay the same.

So what is the best way to store this in sql? For now i can see the only solution is to store annotations as xml string in videos table. There is also an option: to create some kind of new ID in Annotation that will concatinate Video .id and Annotation.id, but i don't feel like it is worth it, because i will probably never search anything in annotations info and they will awlays be displayed with video.

Probably it is pretty common question, but i just have no idea how to search similar problems, so will be glad to hear any tip.

Answer (score 1):

Just because something is called "id" in your input data doesn't mean you can (or should) use it as a primary key. You get data with what are called *natural* keys. Since you don't control them, and you don't want to depend on something you cannot control, you should generate your own keys (*surrogate* keys) and use them internally in your database.

So I would go with something like (let's say you use MySQL)

```
create table videos (
    video_id int(10) auto_increment primary key,
    external_id int(10) unique key
);


create table video_annotations (
    annotation_id int(10) auto_increment primary key,
    video_id int(10),
    external_id int(10),
    constraint video_id_fk foreign key (video_id) references videos(video_id)
);
```

Presumably the source system will not provide videos with duplicate ids (how would it tell them apart otherwise?), and unique key constraint on videos.external_id reflects that in your data model.

Comment: Thx, yep, probably i could do that, but for now xml option looks kinda easier to implement. and i can't see much profit from annotations table.

Comment: Well... you get all the benefits of the relational model. For example, questions like "how many annotations do we have in total" or "how many annotations per video on average" and similar are very easy to answer using the relational model, and not so easy in your model. I mean, if you're using a database... why not use it the right way? Usually pays of in the long term. But it's your decision.